# New-SPConfigurationDatabase cannot connect to database/master unless I am logged into Windows desktop session

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sharepoint, ansible

This one is a doozy. Note, I'm using Ansible to automate, and that's part of the issue.

My ansible playbook fails with the following *if I execute it remotely without being logged into the server*:

```
"stderr": "New-SPConfigurationDatabase : Cannot connect to database master at SQL server at  SERVERNAME.fqdn. 
The database might not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect to it.
```

I have a step in my playbook that confirm I am an AD user with the correct permissions on the database.

Furthermore, this playbook *works if* I happen to be logged into the server (target, where this is running) while the playbook runs. Note, there should be nothing linking the logged-in session to the ansible session, but it's like Active Directory (Kerberos?) only trusts this user when it's "really" logged in.

I did another quick test to see what SQL thought the user was trying to connect, as another task in the playbook:

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = tcp:SERVERNAME; Database = master; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;Encrypt = False;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
$SqlConnection.open()
```

and when I'm logged into the desktop it connects without error. When I'm not logged into the desktop simultaneously, it reports fails with `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\\ANONYMOUS "`

Oh, and the ansible task is running with elevated privs; I don't understand why the SQL client seems to change it's mind which credentials to use based on whether the account is logged into with RDP.

Comment: I haven't used Ansible, so can't point a finger directly.  However that smells very strongly of a double-hop issue.  Are your SPN's correctly configured?

Comment: Agreed, but if that was the case, I would not expect the ansible playbook to work at all -- but it does, but only when I also happen to be logged into the same server via RDP. Unless there is something I'm missing about SPN's that could explain that.

Comment: The SPNs are needed for kerberos authentication  - to get past the double-hop. If you are local then it can drop back to NTLM auth and hence the success locally.